# Is an infinite, recursive predicate valid?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

Consider the following predicate:

$$P(x) =\ "True\ and\ P(x)"$$

Does it make sense to claim that $P(x)$ is true $\forall x$?

*Specifically,*

Consider the case where, instead of a boring $True$, you had some other condition that changed based on $x$, such as the following:

$$P(s, e) =\ "s_1s_2s_3 = s\ \implies\ (s_2 \not = e\ and\ P(s_2, e))"$$

Where $s$ and $e$ are strings, and P essentialy means that no substring of $s$ is equal to $e$. However, the base case of this predicate is an empty string, in which case $s = s_1 = s_2 = s_3$. Can I just ignore $P(s_2, e)$ when $s = s_2$?

Comment: What do you mean with the last question "Can I just ignore P(s_2,e) when s=s_2?" ? Why would we be able to ignore it in that special case?

Comment: @OveAhlman Because it would end up being $s_2 \not= e\ and\ s_2 \not= e\ and\ s_2 \not= e...$

Comment: In standard predicate logic a $P(x)$ defined in this way would not be valid as far as I can tell since any predicate must be built from the bottom up. The definition of predicates in a first order language is inductive.

Answer (score 0):

So the two questions you ask are quite different I think.

The first part: 
$P(x) = "True\ and\ P(x)"$ is equivalent with just $P(x)= P(x)$ the $and \ True$ part does not do anything.

For the second part:
I would sugest doing a distinction between proper substrings and the whole string, else there will not be a stop to the recursive definition, and you would end up with something like in your comment "$s_2\neq e$ and $s_2\neq e$ and ...
How about the following definition instead:

$\\ s=s_1ws_2 \implies (s\neq e \wedge P(s_1w,e) \wedge P(ws_2, e))\\$

Where $s_1$ and $s_2$ are symbols and $w$ is a string.
With a proper base case where we take care of what happen if we only have 1 symbol left in the string. In this way we will not get a problem from calling P with the same thing as went in the first place.